# Convert decimal to a specific scientific notation in bash

Tags: bash, numbers

**PROBLEM**

I was wondering how to perform the following conversion: `0.0000123456` to `0.123456e-04`

My first approach was:

```
printf "%0.6e\n" 0.0000123456
```

But, this command returns:

```
1.234560e-05
```

Thanks so much in advance for any help.

**SOLUTION**

`VAR3` and `VAR4` are numbers, `D` number, `VAR1` is file name 1 and `VAR2` is file name 2.

```
D=`awk -v a="$VAR3" -v b="$VAR4" 'BEGIN{printf "%.6e", (a - b)}'`
case ${D:0:1} in
    [1234567890] )
        EXP=`echo "${D:11:2} - 1" | bc`
        if [ "${#EXP}" -eq 1 ]
            echo "0.${D:0:1}${D:2:-4}D${D:10:1}0$EXP" >> $VAR1\_$VAR2
        else
            echo "0.${D:0:1}${D:2:-4}D${D:10:1}$EXP" >> $VAR1\_$VAR2
        fi
        ;;
    -)
        EXP=`echo "${D:12:2} - 1" | bc`
        if [ "${#EXP}" -eq 1 ]
            echo "0.${D:0:2}${D:3:-4}D${D:11:1}0$EXP" >> $VAR1\_$VAR2
        else
            echo "0.${D:0:2}${D:3:-4}D${D:11:1}$EXP" >> $VAR1\_$VAR2
        fi
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: I'm looking for constructive suggestions, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look like standard scientific notation, so I'm not aware of any Unix tool which will do it by default… but, depending on your requirements, you may be able to use a bit of disgusting Bash:

```
format() {
    local num="$1"
    local prefix="${num%%.*}"
    if [[ "$prefix" == "" ]]; then
        prefix="0"
    fi
    local suffix="${num#*.}"
    if [[ "${suffix}" == "${num}" ]]; then
        suffix="0"
    fi
    if [[ "$prefix" -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo "$prefix.$suffix"
        return 0
    fi
    local without_zeros="${suffix}"
    local num_zeros=0
    while [[ "${without_zeros:0:1}" == "0" ]]; do
        without_zeros="${without_zeros#0}"
        (( num_zeros += 1 ))
    done
    if [[ "$num_zeros" -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "$prefix.$suffix"
    else
        echo "0.${without_zeros}e-$(printf "%02d" "$num_zeros")"
    fi
}


format "0.0001234000" # 0.1234e-03
format "0.0001234" # 0.1234e-03
format "0.1234" # 0.1234
format "1.1234" # 1.1234
format "01.1234" # 01.1234
format "1234" # 1234.0
format "01234" # 01234.0
format ".1234" # 0.1234
```

Now… I'm not sure that I'd *recommend* doing this, as it might make more sense to use a slightly higher level language like Python… but if you need to do it from the shell, that's how I'd do it.